Conditional Formatting Measure : How to return the correct value colour if none of the conditions apply?
How can I amend the below measure to return correct value colours for VAR FailurePrecentageAll / Total Failure %? ))
The first part of the measure works just fine i.e. if I select one TEAM (CX, PURCHASING or TRANSPORT) the measure returns the correct value colour based on set targets :

If no Team is selected then the value colour for Total Failure % is not the correct based on my targets :

Failure % CX, PT & TR (CF) = 
VAR FailurePercentageAll = [Total Failure %]
VAR FailurePercentageTeam = [Failure % (ALL)]
VAR StretchedTargetPercentage =
    SWITCH(
        SELECTEDVALUE('OTIF_ALL'[TEAM]),
        "CX", 0.01,
        "PURCHASING", 0.015,
        "TRANSPORT", 0.015,
        0.04 -- Default value for Total row
    )
VAR TargetPercentage =
    SWITCH(
        SELECTEDVALUE('OTIF_ALL'[TEAM]),
        "CX", 0.013,
        "PURCHASING", 0.019,
        "TRANSPORT", 0.019,
        0.05 -- Default value for Total row
    )
RETURN
    IF(
        HASONEVALUE('OTIF_ALL'[TEAM]),        -- If only one team is selected
        SWITCH(
            TRUE(),
            FailurePercentageTeam <= StretchedTargetPercentage, "#90FE00", -- Green
            FailurePercentageTeam > StretchedTargetPercentage && FailurePercentageTeam <= TargetPercentage, "#FE9400", -- Orange
            FailurePercentageTeam > TargetPercentage, "#FF0000", -- Red
            BLANK() -- Blank for non-matching conditions
        ),
        SWITCH(
            TRUE(),
            FailurePercentageAll <= 0.04, "#90FE00", -- Green
            FailurePercentageAll > 0.04 && FailurePercentageAll <= 0.05, "#FE9400", -- Orange
            FailurePercentageAll > 0.05, "#FF0000", -- Red
            BLANK() -- Blank for non-matching conditions


Can you share some data ?
